# GridView row clicked every time page is rendered

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically everytime I load or reload the page it treats every row in my gridview as if it has been clicked, thus calling the function in the codebehind related to it once for every row which at the time is set to 13 rows max. Thanks for any help.

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Attaching one onclick event for the entire row, so that it will
        // fire SelectedIndexChanged, while we click anywhere on the row.
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] =
          ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView2, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);

    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Comment: That's not a click event, it is expected behavior for RowDataBound

Comment: what is the click event for the gridview? every tutorial that has the whole row as a clickable event is using the RowDataBound

Comment: You are calling the `GetPostBackClientHyperlink` method instead of assigning the onclick to a string of javascript.

Comment: Actually, I don't really know what you are doing. What does `GetPostBackClientHyperlink` return?